# VB. Prime number checker. Invalid input

Tags: vb.net, integer, primes

Can't seem to make my code work when I try to add in `integer.tryparse` to handle invalid input and for the message to read "invalid input". For example, if the number is a letter instead of a number. Here is what I have so far:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        Answer.Text = ""
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
        Dim iNum, iSum As Double
        Dim isPrime As Boolean = False
        iNum = Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
        For i = 2 To Math.Sqrt(iNum) Step 1
            iSum = iNum Mod i
            If (iSum = 0) Then
                isPrime = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If isPrime Then
            Answer.Text = "Is Not Prime"
        Else
            Answer.Text = "Is Prime"
        End If
    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Point to the line where you're using `TryParse`.

Comment: Point to the line where you ask a question.

Comment: Winforms, Webforms, or MVC?  Have you tried using a validator?  Show your TryParse code and describe what is happening.

Comment: If winform: [User Input Validation in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Summary: Handle the validating/validated events.

Comment: I'm not sure where the best place would be to enter in tryparse

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click
    Dim iNum, iSum As Double
    Dim isPrime As Boolean = False
    If Not Integer.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, iNum)
        Answer.Text = "invalid input"
    Else
        For i = 2 To Math.Sqrt(iNum) Step 1
            iSum = iNum Mod i
            If (iSum = 0) Then
                isPrime = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If isPrime Then
            Answer.Text = "Is Not Prime"
        Else
            Answer.Text = "Is Prime"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```